# Are \onehalfspacing and {spacing}{1.5} Supposed to Yield Different Results?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, scaling, output, setspace

I am working on a document which requires for a very small portion of the text, that the spacing between the lines be increased. However, and I don't know why, the `\begin{onehalfspacing}` ... `\end{onehalfspacing}` does not work.

Thus, I sought out an alternative approach, and came up with `\begin{spacing}{1.5}` ... `\end{spacing}` which definitely increased the spacing between the lines in the document I am working on.

However, in trying to figure out why the first approach was not working, I discovered that the two approaches yield different results.

Consider the code,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{onehalfspacing}
\lipsum[3] \vspace{20pt}
\end{onehalfspacing}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\lipsum[3]
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

Now, the way I am seeing it, the two results, which I thought should be the same, are *different*.

QUESTION: What is causing the discrepancy between the two outputs; and which of the two renders a more accurate output of one-and-a-half spacing? Finally, if `\spacing{1.5}` is not accurate, does anyone know the scaling factor I should use to make it as close to one-and-a-half spacing as possible---as this approach works in my document whereas `\onehalfspacing` (for some unbeknownst reason) does not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The environment name is `onehalfspace`, not `onehalfspacing` AND, it is (for a 10pt document) equivalent to `\begin{spacing}{1.25}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{onehalfspace}
\lipsum[3] \vspace{20pt}
\end{onehalfspace}

\begin{spacing}{1.25}
\lipsum[3]
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the relevant code from the style file:

```
% one and a half spacing is 1.5 x pt size
\newenvironment{onehalfspace}{%
  \begingroup
    \onehalfspacing
}{%
  \restore@spacing
}
```

where

```
\newcommand{\onehalfspacing}{%
  \setstretch{1.25}%  default
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.25}%
  \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.213}%
  \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.241}%
  \fi
}
```

and

```
\newenvironment{spacing}[1]{%
  \par
  \begingroup             % moved from \endspacing by PGBR 29-1-91
    \setstretch {#1}%
}{%
  \restore@spacing
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for this informative answer.

Answer (score 3):

The command name convention is explained in the package comments eg

```
% one and a half spacing is 1.5 x pt size
\newenvironment{onehalfspace}{%
```

so note it is 150% of the nominal font size, not of the original baseline spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{onehalfspace}
  \showthe\baselineskip
\end{onehalfspace}
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
> 15.0pt.
l.8   \showthe\baselineskip
```

15 being 1.5 times 10pt which is the current font size.

Comment: I was in the process of accepting the first as your answer arrived, so I was unable to weigh the two. But I am grateful for your help once again.

Comment: actually if I'd read Steven's in detail and noticed he'd posted that package fragment I'd have probably just left a comment but I'll leave it here now. @mlchristians